# How to create a Combinatorial optimization (group sort optimization) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find an algorithm to solve an optimal group sort problem for work. I figure it's a sort of combinatorial optimization, but I could be wrong. I have a list of 36 people who will be grouped into 6 groups of 6 for three rounds with the groups shuffling each time. There are three activities. So two groups doing activity A, two for B, and two for C. Is there an algorithm for me to sort these people in an optimal way such that they each participate in each activity only once, but meet as many people as possible. The goal is to make the teams as unique as possible each round, so as little repeat group mates as possible. This allows for each participant to match with and meet as many people as possible. I figure this is a combinatorial optimization problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I have a static group solution:
Step 1 - A=1,2 B=3,4 C=5,6

Step 2 - A=3,6 B=1,5 C=2,4

Step 3 - A=4,5 B=2,6 C=1,3
But I am struggling to find an optimized dynamic team solution, where the teams change every round, and each individual meets the max individuals in unique groups.

Comment: This problem is closely related to the Social Golfer problem. Three rounds isn't a lot; each person meets at most 15 of the other 35. There should be a straightforward hill climbing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Lets establish some notation. Split each group into 2 implicit "subgroups" of 3 people. Let `A1X` denote the subgroup `X` of the `1`st group of people doing activity `A` in the current round. So `A1X` and `A1Y` make up a group of 6 people doing activity `A` together. `A2X` and `A2Y` make up a second, separate group of 6 people doing activity `A` together.

Make your groups for Round 1. When the round ends, Anyone in an `X` subgroup will rotate activities in "forwards" order (A => B => C => A), and people in subgroup `Y` subgroup will rotate activities in the reverse order (A => C => B => A). Written explicitly:

```
A1X => B1X
A1Y => C1Y
B1X => C1X
B1Y => A1Y
C1X => A1X
C1Y => B1Y
[ same for group 2's ]
```

This ensures 3 of 5 of the other members of the group will be "new".

Next, exchange a member between groups `1`&`2` of the same activity and subgroup label (`X` or `Y`). So pick someone from `A1X` and swap them with someone from `A2X`, and swap someone in `A1Y` with someone in `A2Y` (do the same activities `B` and `C`).

This now ensures that within a subgroup, at least one member (potentially both) will be "new". So, within a group 4 of the 5 other members are guaranteed to be "new", potentially all 5.

Repeat this process for the final round. Do not swap any members (between `1`&`2`) who have already been swapped previously. This will ensure the same 4 out of 5 lower bound we established previously.